# HTML5 video plays/fades out then triggers video underneath

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am trying to do 2 things:

1) Fade an HTML5 video out so that it shows a different HTML5 video layered underneath.

2) After the first video fades out, it triggers the different looping HTML5 video underneath.

For #1, I am unsuccessful at getting the top video to fade. See my code below:

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     video.addEventListener('ended', function () {
           $('#vid').addClass('hide');
           $('video').delay(100).fadeOut();       
     }, false);
    video.play();
    var vid1=document.getElementById("video-loop");
    vid1.addEventListener(function () {
                $('video').delay(100);
            }, false);
    vid1.play();
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="#video">
   <video id="vid" autoplay preload="auto">
      <source src="videos/interactive2_3.webmhd.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
      <source src="videos/interactive2_3.mp4.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
      <source src="videos/interactive2_3.oggtheora.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
   </video>
   <video id="video-loop" preload="auto" loop>
      <source src="videos/interactive2-loop.webmhd.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
      <source src="videos/interactive2-loop.mp4.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
      <source src="videos/interactive2-loop.oggtheora.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
   </video>
</div>
```

For #2, I am looking for any suggestions of how to trigger the bottom video to play as soon as the top video fades out. Javascript or jQuery solution I'm guessing, but I have not found anything in my research that targets a second layered video underneath the first.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: How are you defining the video object?  I see it being used, but it's not defined anywhere.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed – Are you referring to defining the video in my Javascript? If so, any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks so much
!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $('#vid').delay(300).fadeOut();//fade the first video
  var vid1=document.getElementById("video-loop");
  vid1.play();//play the second video
```

In your CSS

```
 #video-loop
 {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:2;
  }
 #vid
  {
 z-index:1;
  }
```

Comment: – Thanks for the response. I adjusted my code above to your suggestions, but am still not getting the first video to trigger the second video on completion. Any other suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Give an equal amount of delay in fading the top video and playing the second video, that should work..

Comment: Do you know what Javascript code I would use to delay the start of a video? I have adjusted my code above, but this doesn't seem to be correct. Thanks again!

Comment: – I set up a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dledet1/6Ye9V/15/. The latest solution still didn't seem to work. I tried some new Javascript code, still not working though. I removed the CSS so that its clearly visible what's going on. The top video should fade out to reveal the bottom video. Top video isn't fading at all. Latest code tries to force a display:none through the JS, but this isn't working either.